# How can i add junit test for a java program using python for continuous integration in jenkins

Tags: java, python, junit, jenkins, continuous-integration

Hello everyone I am a grader for a programming language class and i am trying to use jenkins continuous integration for running some junit tests on their code that is pushed to github.

I was able to get all the committed jobs to the jenkins, but can i run a python file in order to push a testing class to their code and then build their projects an get an xml report about their program test...??

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins allows you to run any external command so you can just call your Python script afterwards